# Как можно создать скрипт миграций по имеющемуся DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, миграция, asp.net-core-2, entity-framework-core-2

У меня есть `Entity Framework Core 2.2` проект и `DataBaseContext` класс в, который формируется автоматически через

```
foreach (var type in entityTypes)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity(type);
}
```

Как я могу программно создать скрипт который сделает миграцию базы данных?

Если более развёрнуто, то сайт состоит из модулей, `DBContext` формируется из всех сущностей базы данных со всех модулей динамически во время инициализации.

Надо научиться перестраивать базу данных при подключении, отключении модулей, или при изменении структуры модели.

Как я понимаю за это отвечает сервис с интерфейсом `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` но как его получить и как с ним работать не понимаю.

Comment: Любопытно. Миграция - это своего рода дифф между нынешним и прошлым состоянием контекста. У вас он создается динамичекски - это нынешнее состояние. А прошлое где-то хранится? Или, как и в простом случае, за основу берется текущая схема БД?

Comment: @Alexander прошлое лежит в MigrationHistory Table